# I have gained knowledge in an undocumented topic, can I start a question and add answers as sub-topics?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I worked with Flash Player ActiveX control in Qt. FlashPlayer is very poorly documented and any information was hard to find. I successfully accomplished many tasks with it, including interoperation and loading from memory (for which it does not have an API).

I'd be happy to share this information with others. My idea is to start a question and add answers as subtopics, like API documentation and common use-cases.

Is that what community wikis are for? Or should I just go to codeproject.com and write an article there?

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: How would you phrase the question?

Comment: Something like: How to use a Flash Player in a Qt application? (with interoperation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can:

- Break each achievement into a proper question
- Provide a working answer

I see no reason why you can't do it. Making it CW or not is really up to you. If you've done the work I see no reason why you can't gain the reputation.

However based on your comment, if you want to create one global multi point question, then rather create a blog post and keep it outside of SO. Or create the blog and the apply the suggestion above.